Debug RPC Function Creation in Supabase
I'm pretty new to database stuff.
I'm using Supabase to create an application where I keep track of the number of likes on certain items ('clicks'). I want to filter items either by the date the likes were added, or by certain categories the items have. So far I have a function that I can call from javascript like:
const { data, error } = await supabase.rpc('rpc_test', { "json_params": {
  "categories": '{"fruits", "test"}',
  "start_date": "2024-04-16 00:22:35.837547+00",
} })

Which should return all items that have a category matching the array I pass in, and the number of clicks that have been created since start_date and before and end_date if provided, or zero if no clicks have been created in that time window. And it so nearly works, but I keep running into errors that I don't know how to fix.
The important tables in my database are:
Items:



id
name




1
apple


2
beet



Clicks:



item_id
created_at




1
2024-04-09


2
2024-04-09



Categories:



id
name




1
vegetable


2
fruit



Item Categories:



item_id
category_id




1
2


2
1



My function query currently looks like this:
create
or replace function public.rpc_test (json_params json default null) returns table (
  id bigint,
  created_at timestamp with time zone,
  name text,
  clicks bigint,
  categories_arr text[]
) as $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
    select
      items.id,
      items.created_at,
      items.name,
      click_counts.clicks,
      item_id_to_cat_array.categories_arr
    from
      items
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT item_categories.item_id AS itemid, array_agg(categories.name) AS categories_arr
          FROM   item_categories
          JOIN   categories ON categories.id = item_categories.category_id
          GROUP  BY item_categories.item_id
      ) item_id_to_cat_array ON items.id = item_id_to_cat_array.itemid
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT item_id as click_item_id, count(c.id) AS clicks
          FROM clicks as c
          WHERE (json_params->>'start_date' IS NULL OR c.created_at >= (json_params->>'start_date')::date)
          AND (json_params->>'end_date' IS NULL OR c.created_at <= (json_params->>'end_date')::date)
          GROUP BY c.item_id
      ) click_counts ON click_item_id = items.id
    where
        json_params->>'categories' IS NULL OR 
        (json_params->>'categories')::text[] && item_id_to_cat_array.categories_arr;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;

The only problem with this is that categories_arr never has any data.
At various points I've had iterations of this that have worked for gathering the information I want but without the filtering in place. I've tried doing things with GROUP BY and HAVING instead, and I'm not really sure where to go.
How can I get more information about what is happening in my query?
I would like to see what categories_arr is at every step in the process, but I don't know how to log that information.

There is no click court in items, but. I guess that you didn't show us the complete items table to be sure

My goal was to have the click count come from the second LEFT JOIN.

also your select must be identocal to the return value

"RPC"? "PRC"? You mean a plain Postgres function? Please don't be cryptic in your question. Show table definitions as CREATE TABLE scripts, and always disclose your version of Postgres.

Also, looks like your JSON input is malformed. Should contain the array like: "categories": "{fruits, test}". But why pass arguments wrapped into JSON? Pass plain values instead.

It's not simple to monitor steps of an SQL query during execution. SQL is a declarative language. You seem to think procedurally. In an actual PL/pgSQL code block you can output anything with RAISE NOTICE between steps. There are even debuggers, like the one built into pgAdmin - which I hardly ever use.
But your function is just a wrapper around one big SQL query. So that wouldn't give you anything.
Assuming a standard many-to-many design like:

How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?

After switching to simpler LANGUAGE sql, your function could look like:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rpc_test (_categories text[], _start_date date = NULL, _end_date date = NULL)
  RETURNS TABLE (id bigint
               , created_at timestamptz
               , name text
               , clicks bigint
               , categories_arr text[])
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT i.item_id
     , items.created_at
     , items.name
     , click_counts.clicks
     , item_id_to_cat_array.categories_arr
FROM  (  -- get distinct item IDs that share any category with input array
   SELECT DISTINCT ic.item_id
   FROM   categories ca
   JOIN   item_categories ic ON ic.category_id = ca.id
   WHERE  ca.name = ANY (_categories)
   ) i
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL ( -- get full array of categories only for qualifying items
   SELECT ARRAY( -- array constructor is a bit cheaper
      SELECT ca.name
      FROM   item_categories ic
      JOIN   categories      ca ON ca.id = ic.category_id
      WHERE  ic.item_id = i.item_id
      ORDER  BY 1  -- optional, to get consistent sort order in output array
      ) AS categories_arr
   ) item_id_to_cat_array
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (   -- get counts only for qualifying items
   SELECT count(*) AS clicks
   FROM   clicks  c
   WHERE  c.item_id = i.item_id
   AND   (_start_date IS NULL OR c.created_at >= _start_date)
   AND   (_end_date IS NULL   OR c.created_at <= _end_date)
   ) click_counts
JOIN   items ON items.id = i.item_id
WHERE  _categories IS NULL OR _categories && item_id_to_cat_array.categories_arr;
$func$;

You had multiple SQL issues. I rewrote the logic to make it work.

Identify items that match any input category. item_categories.item_id is enough for now.
Collect the complete array of categories only for those selected few instead of doing that for all (which is expensive)
Same for clicks.
Finally join to table items to get item details.

Note that this expects input for _categories, as the query wouldn't be good for returning all items. If you need that option, switch back to LANGUAGE plpgsql and fork the case with separate query.
